# Encapsulating constants with dynamic values in a class?

Tags: php, constants

I need to assign functions to constants so this won't work:

```
class Config
{
    const foo = strtoupper('bar');
}
```

Since I need to encapsulate the constant in a class, the alternative `define('foo', strtoupper('bar'));` won't do.

Is my only option is to use public variables? E.g.,

```
class Config
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = strtoupper('bar');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in PHP to define class constants dynamically but you can use static methods to achieve the same result:

```
class Config
{
    public static function FOO()
    {
        return strtoupper('bar');
    }

}

// Usage:
$value = Config::FOO()
```